# Use npm in Meteor packages

Tags: meteor, npm

Was trying to figure out the way to load a npm package into a Meteor one. Specifically I tried with `future-npm`

I've tried to do this:

```
Package.describe({
  summary: "Blah blah",
  version: '0.0.1'
});

Npm.depends({future: "2.3.1"});

Package.onUse(function (api) {
  api.addFiles('lubert.js', 'server');
  api.export('Lubert');
});
```

Unfortunately I got the following console error

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: Npm is not defined
```

I've read the [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full) and there is nothing about to load any dependency

What am I doing wrong?

Update 2: My package.js looks like

```
Package.describe({
  name: 'trepafi:package',
  summary: '',
  version: '0.0.3',
  git: 'https://github.com/trepafi/meteor-package.git'
});

Npm.depends({
  "future": "2.3.1"
});

Package.onUse(function(api) {
  api.versionsFrom('1.0');
  api.use(['tracker', 'underscore'], ['client']);
  api.addFiles(['package.js'], ['client']);
  api.export('Package', ['client']);
});
```

Update 1: My package.json looks like

```
{
  "name": "trepafi-package",
  "version": "0.0.3",
  "description": "Package for Meteor",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/trepafi/meteor-package.git"
  },
  "author": "Lubert Palacios",
  "license": "MIT",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/trepafi/meteor-package",
  "dependencies": {
    "future": "^2.3.1"
  }
}
```

I've also tried with meteorhacks:npm without success. 
It'd be nice if I can use a "native" way

Comment: What's your package file structure ? Your syntax looks good to me.

Comment: https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm This should do the trick

Comment: @saimeunt Just added it

Comment: @Sindis I've already tried it without success

Comment: You don't need to provide a package.json, only a package.js living in its own package directory.

Comment: @saimeunt, sorry too late for me! just added it as well

Comment: You don't need a package.json AT ALL, you can remove it because Meteor will ignore its content. Exporting `Package` is probably a bad idea because it's already a global Meteor namespace. Try replacing `1.0` with `METEOR@1.0` in the `versionsFrom` call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be grouping all `Npm.require`s at the end of your `package.js` file.

For `future-npm`. You don't need `Npm.depends` in `package.js`, Silly. It's already included in meteor.. just `Npm.require` somewhere and you're good to go. To do that:

1. Don't be ambiguous with the `package.js` name. Use the `trepafi:package.js` instead.
2. You don't need `package.json`.. `Npm.depends` has got you covered.
3. Remove this: `api.addFiles(['package.js'], ['client']);` as it looks like a circular dependency.. *Yo dawg i herd you liek package.js in you package.js*.. not cool, Xzibit.
4. And since Npm.require only works server-side, you need to include `trepafi:package.js` as server-side. e.g:

   `api.addFiles(['trepafi:package.js'], ['server']);`

So your structure should *at least* be:

```
trepafi:package/
  - package.js
  - trepafi:package.js
  - <other files..>
```

You don't need package.json for `Future`.. it's already included with Meteor.

Your `package.js` should look like:

```
Package.describe({
  name: 'trepafi:package',
  summary: '',
  version: '0.0.3',
  git: 'https://github.com/trepafi/meteor-package.git'
});

Package.onUse(function(api) {
  api.versionsFrom('METEOR@1.0');
  api.use(['tracker', 'underscore','meteor'], ['client']);
  api.addFiles(['trepafi:package.js'], ['server']);
  api.export('Package', ['client']);
});

//if you really need Npm.depends:

Npm.depends({
   'prerender-node': '1.0.6',
   'send' : '0.10.1'
});

// we don't need no package.json
```

Your `trepafi:package.js` should look like:

```
var Future = Npm.require('future');
var future = new Future();

// use your future to make Doc Brown proud.

var useFuture = function(asyncFunc) { //expects function with callback somewhere
    asyncFunc(function(err, result) {
        if(err) future.throw("OMG something went wrong!");
        else return future.return(result);
    });
    return future.wait();
};

Meteor.startup(function() {
   //something      
});
```

### READ:

Notable changes in `package.js` are `versionsFrom` and `api.use` now has `meteor` added to it.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for that.  I was wondering why I was getting "Npm is missing" in my browser log, referring to a file in ./myPackage/server.  Using Meteor.isServer fixed it, but really shouldn't be need for a file in a server directory.  So ... apparently the 'client' and 'server' declarations in api.addfiles() have precedence, and make such directory names unnecessary inside a package.